# Convert variable name to string MATLAB

Tags: matlab, variables, save

I have a function in which I need to input a name which later assigns a name to the output the matfile.

```
function(filename2) % we need to input i.e "systolicAmplitude"
filename=[HBO;HBR];
matfileGroupInfo=strcat(filename2,'.mat');
save(matfileGroupInfo)
```

I faced an error "string cannot be used as a variable name". Any solution how I can solve the problem?

**I have the option to re-write the code as below:

```
 function(filename) % we need to input i.e "systolicAmplitude"
vec=[HBO;HBR];
matfileGroupInfo=strcat(filename2,'.mat');
save(matfileGroupInfo,'vec')
```

but it saves the variable under name of systolicAmplitude.vec. This is not favored for me.

Comment: Those snippets are sooooo confusing. What `HBO` and `HBR` are? How are you retrieving them? What is that function declaration?

Comment: Try using single quotes in `'systolicAmplitude'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess something else is wrong. I fixed the function format in your code and it works fine and saves the the *.mat file in the current directory.

```
function Blah(filename2) % we need to input i.e "systolicAmplitude"
vec=['HBO';'HBR'];
matfileGroupInfo=strcat(filename2,'.mat');
save(matfileGroupInfo,'vec')
```

When you call the function like `Blah('systolicAmplitude')`, it writes the 'vec' into the mat file and the saves `systolicAmplitude.mat` in the current directory.